# 整日 Vs 整天 Is there any difference?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Is there any difference between 整日  and 整天

整日 : whole day refers to only day ?

整天 : whole day refers to day & night?

Dictionary Meaning:
整日 zhěngrì all day along, whole day
整天 zhěngtiān whole day

Comment: Related: [Is Sunday 星期天 or 星期日?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16265/is-sunday-%e6%98%9f%e6%9c%9f%e5%a4%a9-or-%e6%98%9f%e6%9c%9f%e6%97%a5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually they're the same, they both mean a whole day. However:

- 整日 is more formal; it is always used in written language.
- 整天 is casual, such as when your mom complaining about you:

  > 整天玩游戏
  > "playing games all day".

Comment: Is there anyword Day and Night equivalent in chinese?

Comment: Surprise, surprise -- 整天整夜

Comment: @user27485 Yes. 日夜, such as 日夜不停。

Comment: @user27485 just to supplement, there is 日夜 but not *天夜.

Comment: 日以繼夜 is  similar to 日夜不停

Comment: and also “不舍昼夜”